# How to change any function Component's state from another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-state-management

React 16.8 brought the state and setState functionality into function based Component.

My question is:
**In the case of Function based component is there any way to change the state outside the function ?**

**Example**:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';


function fetch_all_products(){
    Axios.get(url)
        .then(
            response => {
                let data = response.data;

                //FROM HERE I WANT TO SET THIS DATA INTO SHOP COMPONENT
                // STATE (i.e, products) AND RE RENDER THE SHOP COMPONENT
            }
        )   
}



export default function Shop(){
    const[products, setProducts] = useState(products['Rice','Oil']);

    let all_products = products.map( product => {
        return(
            <li>product</li>
        )
    });

    return(
        <>
            <h2>The Grocery Shop </h2>
            <button onClick={fetch_all_products}>See All Products </button>
            <ul>
                {all_products}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}
```

I want to change the Shop component's state (products) outside the function by using 'fetch_all_products' function.

Comment: use a callback inside fetch all

Comment: Would you kindly describe with code ? @DennisVash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Finally I come up with an easy solution.**

Instead using the essential function outside the component function, I used it inside the component function ('fetch_all_products' used inside 'Shop').

[There was a silly syntactical mistake in my question, that is also corrected here]

**Code:**

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

export default function Shop() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(['Rice', 'Oil']);

  function fetch_all_products() {
    Axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      let data = response.data;
      setProducts(data);
    });
  }

  let all_products = products.map((product) => <li>{product}</li>);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>The Grocery Shop </h2>
      <button onClick={fetch_all_products}>See All Products </button>
      <ul>{all_products}</ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Thank you everybody who tried to help me in different ways.

Comment: please try to upvote or accept the answer which helped you

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer also but stackoverflow doesn't except my upvote due to my very low reputation point. Anyway, Thank you @TapanDave

Comment: alright thanks,just accept as answer if you able to

Answer (score 1):

You can use **callback** to do this. This is how:

1.) Pass in a callback to your original `fetch_all_products` function. Like so:

```
function fetch_all_products(callback){
    Axios.get(url)
        .then(
            response => {
                let data = response.data;      
                callback(data);
            }
        )   
}
```

2.) Make a class method (a function inside the class) which will call `fetch_all_products` and call this method via `onClick`. Like so:

```
fetchProducts = () => {
    fetch_all_products(data => {
        // use the DATA here to set your state or modify it
    }
}
```

3.) Call this above method via `onClick` like this:

```
<button onClick={fetchProducts}>See All Products </button>
```

Comment: In point number 2 you wrote to  make a class method but my component is fully 'Function component'. Here is no class @Devashish

Comment: @Shamim sorry my bad. although, the principal still remains the same. Have you tried this approach yet?

Answer (score 0):

other way you can do something like this,promise would be the api call you are doing and then resolving it when response arrives and setting state with setData:

**Example**

```js
const { useState } = React;

function fetchData() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random()), 500))
}

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(0)

  function onClick() {
    fetchData().then(setData)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Get data</button>
      <div>{data}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```